# Show that $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has seven subgroups of order 2.

Tags: normal-subgroups

Show that $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has seven subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: Count the elements of order 2. Each is the generator of a subgroup. And each element of your group is of order 2, except the identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$([0]; [0]; [0])$; $([1]; [0]; [0])$; $([0]; [1]; [0])$; $([1]; [1]; [0])$; $([0]; [0]; [1])$; $([1]; [0]; [1])$; $([0]; [1]; [1])$; $([1]; [1]; [1])$:

Now $[0]+[0] = [1]+[1] = [0]$ in $\mathbb Z_2$, and the direct sum construction is defined with operation:
$$(x_1; y_1)(x_2; y_2) = (x_1x_2; y_1y_2):$$
Thus, if we take any $a = (x; y; z)$ element in $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ then we must have $a_2 =
(x; y; z)(x; y; z) = (x + x; y + y; z + z) = ([0]; [0]; [0])$, the identity of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$.

There are seven elements of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ of order 2 (every element except $e$), and for each such $a$ there is a subgroup of order 2, namely $fe; ag$. This gives seven different subgroups.

However, this is all of the subgroups of order 2, since a subgroup of order 2 has $e$ and one other element.